# How to remove "pictureframe" in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've been debugging my html/css webpage in google chrome. When I decided to take a look at it in Internet Explorer I discovered that the pictures in my header all have grey "frames" around them. Each picture is added like this:

```
 .menuItem {
margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

<a href='input.php' class='menuitem'><img src="icons/pic.png"/></a>
```

How do I get rid of these frames?

All answers appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you supply some html and CSS? maybe it's the border for links?, to solve that just specify `border: 0;` to the images.

Comment: @jackJoe Please take a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your images nested in an `anchor` tag? E.g:

```
<a href="#">
   <img />
</a>
```

If so this may be a default link border.

Try setting this in your css:

```
a img {
   border:0;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. I use a different tag to add images.

Comment: @NorS - what's different about your example compared to this one? This does sound like the correct answer. Have you tried it? Add the CSS code above to your stylesheet and tell us whether it works or not.

Comment: I must have copypasted this incorrectly the first time. It obviously works. Thank you both!